# How to check for valid user and then continue submitting data

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET to submit data from a form to a database.

But before submit I want to check if the current user us valid. If not I want to use the login control registration form where an existing user can enter his user id and password then go back to the previous page to submit the form data.

Example:
Assume a page having 3 textboxes and one button. Once the user clicks the button I want to check if the user is already logged in or not. If not I want to open the login page so he can provide his credentials and after that execute the previous page submit function without the user having to click again.

Comment: Please explain in normal english, or at least with some kind of punctuation. The way you wrote this, it's unreadable.

Comment: @JoachimVR I think I managed to guess what he is after

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about form validation? The easiest way to do this is with a postback. Put a button on the form, that button will post back the form to itself, and fire the button_Click event. Inside that event you can put some C# code that will validate the user's name and password. Then you can show a label on the form that indicates the credentials are not correct.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can save information about user, using session:

```
Session["UserLoggedIn"] = true;
```

When you want to check, if user is logged in, check like this:

```
if(Session["UserLoggedIn"] != null)
{
  // User is logged in
}
else
{
  // User is not logged in, so redirect to login page
  Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
}
```

if you want to redirect back, after successful log in operation. you can use QueryString. So instead of:

```
  Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
```

redirection will be:

```
  Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?RedirectUrl=your current form url");
```

In login page, you can read QueryString:

```
string redirectUrl = Request.QueryString["RedirectUrl"];
```

After login operation, use redirectUrl value, to redirect back:

```
Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks  after redirect the page how to execute submit function with out click . is there any way to call function at the redirect time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you post your "submit function" in you question?

Answer (score 0):

i hope i have tried to understand you.

firstly, i would like to explain what you want.

You want to check user logged in before submit, and if he is not logged in you want him to redirect to login page after he logs in u want to come back on the same page. and perform your click function.

```
RetrunUrl
```

return url in your querystring will help to return to back to your original page. and u can save the details of the previous page in session and once user logs in and redirects back to original back perform your click event there. by validating you session value,

once you are done with your whole process remember to abandon your current session details

Comment: @user1127905 if you found any answers helpful or working, you can accept the answer by clicking on the outline of a check mark to the left of each answer. also you can upvote the answers by clicking the arrow which pointing to the top which also in left of each answer